# Ansible with a bastion host / jump box?

Tags: ansible

I'm fairly certain I've seen a feature in the ansible documentation where you can tell it that to connect to certain hosts it first needs to tunnel through a DMZ host. I can't however seem to find any documentation outside of some debates on the mailing lists.

I'm aware of hacking this in with an ssh config like on this page http://alexbilbie.com/2014/07/using-ansible-with-a-bastion-host/ however that's an overcomplicated kludge for an extremely common requirement in any kind of mildly regulated environment.

Is there a way to do this without using custom ssh config includes and voodoo netcat sorcery?

Answer (score 30):

With Ansible 2, this is a [built-in option](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to):

> ### How do I configure a jump host to access servers that I have no direct access to?
>
> With Ansible 2, you can set a *ProxyCommand* in the *ansible_ssh_common_args* inventory variable. Any arguments specified in this variable are added to the sftp/scp/ssh command line when connecting to the relevant host(s). Consider the following inventory group:
>
> ```
> [gatewayed]
> foo ansible_host=192.0.2.1
> bar ansible_host=192.0.2.2
> ```
>
> You can create *group_vars/gatewayed.yml* with the following contents:
>
> ```
> ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@gateway.example.com"'
> ```
>
> Ansible will append these arguments to the command line when trying to connect to any hosts in the group *gatewayed*. (These arguments are used in addition to any *ssh_args* from *ansible.cfg*, so you do not need to repeat global *ControlPersist* settings in *ansible_ssh_common_args*.)
>
> Note that *ssh -W* is available only with OpenSSH 5.4 or later. With older versions, it’s necessary to execute *nc %h:%p* or some equivalent command on the bastion host.

Comment: Note that if you copy the `ansible_ssh_common_args` line into your *inventory* file, you need equal signs instead of colons! Boy that took a while to catch...

Comment: How to specify a jump box one the command line, for a given playbook?

Comment: Link in `built-in-option` is expired. I just want to update [new link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to) for other people.

Answer (score 16):

If your jump box needs a private key file to connect (even if it's the same key as the one used for the private subnet instances), use this instead:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i <path-to-pem-file> -W %h:%p -q user@gateway.example.com"'
```

I spent hours trying to fix a problem that now seems like a simple and obvious solution.

Comment: If the private key file is in a standard location, specifying the path explicitly should not be necessary.

Comment: I also needed to download the private key from the jump box/gateway and specify the path to it.  Seems not ideal.  If there is a way to not have to do that download, and specifying, I would be curious to know.

Answer (score 2):

As Ansible uses SSH, you can specify a bastion host in the standard SSH config way:

e.g. to connect through a bastion host for all servers that have a name like "*.amazonaws.com":

```
Host *.amazonaws.com
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p my_bastion_host.example.org
```

When `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` runs, it will read in your SSH configuration file and apply it for connections.  You can also specify which SSH configuration file is read by using the `ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS` environmental variable or by using the `-F` flag when calling the command.

You are also able to specify more SSH arguments in the [ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#openssh-specific-settings).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of and what I could consider the wrong way to do it ( if I was designing ansible ). In Capistrano this is literally a one liner.

Comment: I ran into a similar case and would have liked to be able to specify a "config file/option factory" script on the command line.  Out of curiosity, can you add your one-liner approach to your question?

Comment: There's a gateway host option in Capistrano (a similar tool) that really should be in ansible. If I'm copying 15 lines of boilerplate for something i feel like it should be built into the tool.