# Ansible, connecting to bastion server in AWS VPC, host unreachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, amazon-vpc

How can I connect to a bastion server in a AWS VPC using Ansible 2.x to perform a Docker swarm setup? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408017/ansible-with-a-bastion-host-jump-box) and the [official FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to).

Already tried providing the following via `--extra-vars`:
`ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q user@my.bastion.server.com"'` or even using `ansible.cfg` with the parameter above, or even something like:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=600s -J ec2- 
user@my.bastion.dns.com
```

I tried a lot of combinations but I’m always getting this error message running a ping command in a playbook:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the 
host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 10.1.xx.xx port 22: Operation timed 
out\r\n",
```

Probably worth mentioning that:

1. I’m able to connect to the private hosts in my VPC normally using *ssh -J* option, example: `ssh -J user@my.bastion.server.com user@vpc.host.private.ip` .
2. I’m using Ansible’s ec2.py dynamic inventory with ec2.ini configured to map the private ips for a given tag entry.

Comment: Since you're timing out, something is likely misconfigured with your VPC's route tables and NACLs, or your bastion instance's security group(s) are blocking the incoming network traffic.  

When you successfully connect to the bastion host, is it from the same computer that your playbook is executing the SSH playbook on? Or is the playbook running the SSH playbook on some other remote computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a ssh misconfiguration problem.

I was able to fix with the configuration with those parameters.

**1) Ansible.cfg file**

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q $BASTION_USER@$BASTION_HOST" -o ControlPersist=600s 
control_path=%(directory)s/%%h-%%r
pipelining = True
```

**2) Ec2.ini file**

```
[ec2]
regions = us-xxxx-x
destination_variable = private_ip_address
vpc_destination_variable = private_ip_address
```

**3) Playbook Execution Command**

```
export BASTION_USER=xxx-xxxx;
export BASTION_HOST=ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.xxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com;
ansible-playbook -u ec2-xxxx \
 -i ./inventory/ec2.py \
 ./playbook/ping.yml \
 --extra-vars \
 "var_hosts=tag_Name_test_private ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/my-test-key.pem" -vvv
```

And voila!

[image: successful ping]