# Ansible: How to set up Ansible so bastion's *SSH config* is used to access target host

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

**Background/goal:**
I need to run Ansible from my laptop > bastion > a target host b/c target hosts are behind firewalls that I do not control (IOT devices). I have active reverse tunnels between target hosts and the bastion, such that I can SSH into my bastion and then can run `ssh <hostname>` (where 'hostname' exists in the bastion's SSH config) to access any target hosts.

All target hosts have unique entries in the bastion's SSH config file so that they can be accessed like this (they all use the same host--localhost, same identity key--on the bastion but also located locally if helpful, *however all entries have ports which are necessarily unique*).

**What I've tried:**
I have tried the official Ansible recommendation to set up a jump host: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-configure-a-jump-host-to-access-servers-that-i-have-no-direct-access-to, which is also copied at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850087/10145168

However, this fails with the error:

```
UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

**Problem:**
I believe the issue is that I need my SSH command from the bastion to target host to be in this form: `ssh <hostname>` (where all my Ansible hostnames are also an alias in the bastion's SSH config). Otherwise Ansible tries to connect to the target host over port 22, which fails; also it won't know where to find the SSH key to access the target host from the bastion unless it uses the bastion's SSH config file.

How can I make Ansible use the ssh command of `ssh <hostname>` or `ssh <user>@<hostname>`, which both should work as long as there is no port, and pick up the bastion's `~/.ssh/config`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using SSH proxy, the ssh config file on your proxy is not taken into account. If you have the configuration above(from ansible website), then for SSH(and ansible) it's like you have a direct connection. It's only your local SSH config file that matters.

If you really would like to use the config file from your bastion, then you should bring it to the machine where you run ansible and perhaps only apply the part of the config to the set of machines that live beyond the proxy.

That being said, also must be mentioned that it's not a best practice to have any SSH configs outside ansible since this is making your playbooks hard to support. Any SSH configs you may have must go in your `ansible.cfg`, your group vars and your inventory files. I would recommend you to translate what you have in your SSH config file into ansible config file.

Lastly, remember that ansible relies on SSH. If you can successfully SSH to your desired machines, then ansible will be able to do so as well. It's always best do your SSH debugging directly first and then switch to ansible.

Comment: Agree with comment about avoiding use of SSH configs by Ansible.  You can maintain separate SSH config just for Ansible, in same repo not the default config location - this might make some things easier but is another place to look for config.