# Ansible dynamically add proxy host, then use proxy host to login to machine behind it, without ssh_config

Tags: ssh, ansible

SO I would like to provision a proxy-host ( i can do this), add it to the dynamic ansible inventory via add_host (done),

Then in the next play, run tasks on that proxy-host, to find another machine behind it, update something ansible side to know this new host's location, and that It needs to be proxy jumped via this current proxy-host,

Then in the next play target this new machine behind the proxy-host.

I am at a lost here, i was hoping to do it without all of this ssh_config changes... is this possible, has anyone done this, thoughts?

Comment: It's possible to proxy connections using the `--ssh-common-args='-o ProxyCommand ssh -q bastion.example.com -W "[%h]:%p"'` however not certain about the dynamic aspect. You could set the proxy configuration in your `~/.ssh/config` for the hosts behind the bastion server, that would probably work (i.e. `Host *.internal\n\tProxyCommand ssh -q bastion.example.com -W "[%h]:%p"`) - e.g. all `ssh` connections to `*.internal` should be proxied through the bastion server. I don't see how you'd configure the `ssh` proxy connections without configuring `ssh`.

Comment: The questions title exactly says without the ssh_config. Thanks for the help masseyb
Also i am getting down_votes for what... If you have an answer that would be alot more help than just down voting. Cuz I am still researching...

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to my question. I think that it is a perfectly valid question, and alot the documentation from Ansible semi-answers this question, it is not put into the context of being dynamic, nor is it stated that it can be done completely dynamically.

Pretext: Using terraform, within ansible to generate hosts, with the following configuration:
control_box (running ansible/terraform from)----> dynamically created Bastion/proxy/jump_host ---> some_server(behind the bastion)

Playbook:

```
#Make the bastion host, and add it to the just_created group
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  roles:
  - terraform_logic_add_host_logic 

- hosts: just_created #aka bastion
  tasks:
  - name: Include task list in play
    include: "get_the_private_ip_and_add_to_behind_bastion_group.yml"

  # Login into behind_bastion group.....
  - hosts: behind_bastion_group
  vars:
  - ansible_connection: ssh
  - ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh -i {{ some_pem_key }} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p -q ec2-user@{{ the_bastion_ip }}"'
  tasks:
    - name: Include task list in play
      include: "do_stuff_finally.yml"
```

I have done my research as well FYI:
Posts such as this, do not show the complete End2End solution of doing this all dynamically...

https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/

[Ansible with a bastion host / jump box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408017/ansible-with-a-bastion-host-jump-box)

https://selivan.github.io/2018/01/29/ansible-ssh-bastion-host.html